# 센스 vs 눈치 - Notable differences?

Tags: translation, spoken-korean, written

I asked a question about 눈치 and have a good understanding of what it means.

센스 is another word that I understand as well but what would be a good way to differentiate between the 2?

`눈치 없다` - has no awareness or doesnt pick up on social cues, environment

`센스 없다` - has no `sense`, not in the English meaning, but doesn't have the capacity or understanding to figure out a good course of action in whatever circumstance

Things like using non-honorifics to elders have been used to describe something with no 눈치.

I was once told that I had no 센스 when it comes to taking pictures.

Would these be accurate definitions or is there a better way differentiate the 2? In my eyes, while they aren't 100% interchangeable, they do have similarities to where if you used one over the other, I would still know what someone meant.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

센스 is a more general term for the ability to "understand the situation" or "make a good choice", especially when it's hard to explain logically.  I think 눈치 is more exclusive to "reading other people's feeling" (or "reading the atmosphere").

So, for example, if a person is good at real estate investment, we may say "저 사람 집을 고르는 센스가 있다." (He/she knows how to pick a good house.)  You can't use 눈치 here: the person is not trying to read how you feel about it.

I think it can also mean "common sense".  If someone lacks common sense and does something awkward/idiotic, you can say "넌 왜 그렇게 센스가 없냐?"

- Colloquially, 개념 (originally "concept") is also used in a similar way, though I think it's stronger.  To me, 센스가 없다 is something like wearing a pair of sandals with socks on a date.  개념이 없다 is something like running red light in front of a kindergarten.  Finally, 눈치가 없다 is like staying late in a party of three when the other two are clearly trying to hit it off.

Comment: appreciate the explanation, that makes a lot of sense

Comment: 개념 is a stronger version of 센스 then? kinda like `hate` is a stronger version of `dislike`?

Comment: These things can be tricky (and change from speaker to speaker), but my take is: you can be a good person without 센스, but if you don't have 개념, you aren't a good person. Hope it makes sense (ha ha) for you.

Comment: 센스 relates to one's behaviour that gives positive impressions to others; 개념, to norms and manners. They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

> 눈치 is a major factor to be a usual person
>
> 센스 is one factor to be a superior better than a usual person

**1)** When we meet for a photo, then we should wear a neat style. But
if someone wear a gym suit (i.e. *he did not make an effort*), then he
has no tact. Further, if some makes a grimace, then he has no tact.
When someone has a dance dress or makes V-shape fingers, then he has
a sense.

**2)** 그애 센스가 장난 아니다 His sense is not a simple act = He has a terrific sense (so that almost
girl draw a romance with him)

**@** 그애 센스가 장난 아니다. He is grotesque (for instance, he wear
Halloween costume at Christmas)

**3)** 눈치밥 먹어서 눈치 많이 봐 He walks on eggshells, since he
received a lot of scolds (=he ate a rice of scolds).

**@** When he has no tact, then he would have a lot of difficulties
during army duty period or at workplace. When he have no sense, then
I suggest that he would be a officer man, but not entertainer.